# If i add 1 year to Datepicker's endDate() its showing 2 months lesser

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I am facing problem in adding 1 year exact to a date object(from date) and set it as endDate to my to datepicker. It is adding all perfect except months are less by 2. This is the code I have used to add 1 year.

```
var fromMaximumDate = new Date(Date.parse($('#dtFromDate').val()));
    fromMaximumDate.setFullYear(fromMaximumDate.getFullYear() + 1);
    fromMaximumDate.setMonth(fromMaximumDate.getMonth());
    fromMaximumDate.setDate(fromMaximumDate.getDate());
    fromMaximumDate.setHours(fromMaximumDate.getHours());
    fromMaximumDate.setMinutes(fromMaximumDate.getMinutes());
    fromMaximumDate.setSeconds(fromMaximumDate.getSeconds());.
```

**Image below:**

[image: as seen in the image attached]

Comment: I tried your code in a JS fiddle and it works fine.  I believe the `Date.parse($('#dtFromDate').val())` is the problem.

Comment: Its unexpected. You can try adding 12 month or adding 365 days can be solution to your issue.

Comment: @Pawan It is giving same result even if i add getMonth()+12

Comment: May be date time setted incorrect in user machine. Its not possible. Else you could have one jugaad to this solution to add 14 month.

Comment: Varshaan. Did you get the solution?

Comment: @pawan not yet checking if any problem with jQueryUI

Comment: ok varshaan please post the cause of issue and solution when you find the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
var fromMaximumDate = new Date(Date.parse($('#dtFromDate').val()));
alert(fromMaximumDate.getMonth());
```

If you see the month having 2 added to it, then you know that your `Date.parse()` code is the culprit.

Comment: Its is giving same result even after using    `var fromMaximumDate = new Date($('#dtFromDate').val());`    by excluding Date.parse. it is setting month  properly in date view but in month view it is disabled

Comment: This sounds like a JQuery UI problem then.

Comment: i agree with you coz there is no other problems visible for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
Your code looks right to me. Have a look to this fiddle link.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dscfzwx8/

```
Just remember that int ISO notation 2015 is the year, 05 is the month and 07 is the day
```